# How can I rename of the MainPage.xaml and MainPage.cs in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, rename

I am a newbie in windows phone 7.
WHen I add a new windows phone 7 project into visual studio, it creates MainPage.xaml and MainPage.cs as default. After that, I want to rename these file to HomePage.xaml and HomePage.cs, so I selected this file (in solution explorer) then pressed F2 and entered the new name. The renaming was ok. But when I pressed F5 to run my project, Visual studio stoped at the code line as below image.[image] If I press F10 or F5 to continue, my application down.

If you know about this problem, please tell me.

Thanks.
Binh Nguyen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your main page in Properties -> WMAppManifest.xml

```
  <DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage="SomeOtherPage.xaml"/>
```